# Get selected text from HTML by javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a page with formated text and a toolbar (images with click events) beside it.
One of the tool-commands is meant to be "mark yellow". *(The text has to be read only and is formated.)*

I tried to use `document.getSelection()` and `window.getSelection()`, but they seem to be designed for input fields only.

The other problem is, that as I click the tool bar my selection gets lost.

How do I get the selected text without loosing the selection?

### Solution:

The clue was to use `onmousedown=""`
or jQuery: `.mousedown()` function to avoid loosing the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to [get text selection with Javascript](http://www.codetoad.com/javascript_get_selected_text.asp).